# Linux file get lines with column matching specific datetime range

Tags: linux, shell

How to get lines matching datetime range. For example, get all lines between 2017-09-08 00:00:00 and 2017-09-09 00:00:00. Delimiter is space.

file:

```
2017-09-07 19:00:01 a
2017-09-08 20:00:01 a
2017-09-08 21:00:03 a
2017-09-10 19:00:01 a
```

output:

```
2017-09-08 20:00:01 a
2017-09-08 21:00:03 a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$1FS$2> "2017-09-08 00:00:00"  && $1FS$2 <"2017-09-09 00:00:00"' inputfile
2017-09-08 20:00:01 a
2017-09-08 21:00:03 a
```

Or you can store the times in variables:

```
awk -v start="2017-09-08 00:00:00" -v end="2017-09-09 00:00:00" '$1FS$2> start  && $1FS$2 <end' inputfile
2017-09-08 20:00:01 a
2017-09-08 21:00:03 a
```

Explanation:

`$1` means the first column
`$2` means the second column
`FS` means field separator, which is by default is space. 
`$1FS$2` means first two columns together as one entity. This was needed because there is space between your date and time column.

Comment: Great. Can you explain the meaning of "$1FS$2"?

Comment: @user7328234 check updated answer with explanation. Hope it helps.